# Where to put object-cache in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, guava

I want to use some caching from the Guava-library in my Grails app. Is a service class with a non-static field and some getter the best place to put this cache into? Or should  it be static or declared somewhere else?

Basic Example:

```
class TestService {
      def getCachedValue(Test test) {
          return testCache.get(test)
      } 

  def testCache = new CacheBuilder()
    .maximumSize(2000)
    .weakKeys()
    .weakValues()
    .expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build(
        new CacheLoader<Test, Date>() {
                ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a service **is** the best idea for this. However, making it static is a bit unnecessary since by default services are singletons.

The fact a service is a singleton, and is exposed to not only your controllers but other artifacts within your Grails application make it a perfect fit for accessing an object cache. A single point of access.

Comment: Is it possible to access other services in a static Cache?

Comment: What do you mean by "static Cache"?

Comment: A statically typed cache: `static def testCache = ...`. The reason why I'm asking is, I dont know how the framework assures there is only one instance of my service class. They could be recreated for several reasons. And there are several opinions stating that services should not have an internal state. To use a statically typed cache will ensure that all (possible) instances will have the same state.

Comment: The Spring Framework (which is the underpinnings of Grails) will create a single instance of your service (as a bean) and you can inject that into other artifacts (like controllers, services, and domains using def mySpecialService). There is no need to go the route of using static like that, so long as you never create an instance of your service manually and always use an injected reference then you will be fine.